# How to use axios to edit and update a page's html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I'm using axios and an API to get a page's HTML, editing the HTML, and putting it back via a POST request to the API. I'm successful in retrieving and editing the HTML but I can't figure out how to put it back/change the webpage's HTML.

I tried using a PUT request instead of a POST request, but I get a 405 error that the PUT method is not allowed for the webpage.

```
axios.get(url, {
  auth: {
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD
  },
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }
})
.then( (response) => {
  version = response.data.version.number;
  body = response.data.body.storage.value;

  // takes the body HTML and formats all the links
  newBody = middleware.formatLinks(body);

  data = {
    "type": "page",
    'version': {'number': version + 1},
    'body': {
      'storage': {
        'value': newBody,
        'representation': 'storage'
      }
    }
  }

  // put the body HTML back into the page
  axios.post(url, {
    data: {
      "type": "page",
      'version': {'number': version + 1},
      'body': {
        'storage': {
          'value': newBody,
          'representation': 'storage'
        }
      }
    }
  }, { 
    auth: {
    username: USERNAME,
    password: PASSWORD
    },
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
  })
  .then( (response) => {
    console.log(response.data);  
  })
  .catch( (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
})
.catch( (error) => {
  console.log(error);
})
```

I expect the page to now be updated with all the links formatted to my liking. However the page is unchanged. When I `console.log(response.data)` after making the post request, the output is a string of `newBody`, when I expect it to be the JSON object

```
data: {
  'type': 'page',
  'version': {'number': version + 1},
  'body': {
    'storage': {
      'value': newBody,
      'representation': 'storage'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You are showing what appears to be the client side of the conversation here, when the action must take place on the server side. Something needs to the your posted HTML and save it to the file system somehow.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I think I understand what you're getting at but what if this webpage is already online somewhere and I don't have direct editing access to it? In other words, I can only interact with it via an API. Does this still apply?

Comment: You'd have to talk to the owner of the API, I guess. There's nothing you can do from the client to affect the how the server is programmed...

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment in @Aman Raj's answer, I have the code working in python but translating it to nodejs was giving me issues. So I circumvented my problem by calling my python script in nodejs with the python-shell package.

```
let {PythonShell} = require('python-shell');
...
const formatLinks = (id) => {
    let options = {
      mode: 'text',
      pythonOptions: ['-u'], // get print results in real-time
      scriptPath: './python/', // path to my python scripts

      // pass in the page id, username, and password to API request
      args: [id, USERNAME, PASSWORD] 
    };

    PythonShell.run('script.py', options, (err, results) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      // results is an array consisting of messages collected during execution
      console.log('results: %j', results);
    });
}
```

Comment: Note that for my python script, I used the python module 'requests' to retrieve and update the page's html. I've had a lot more success with requests than with axios unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine. It may be possible that you are accessing an API which does not support editing it.

> The HyperText Transfer Protocol (HTTP) 405 Method Not Allowed response
>   status code indicates that the request method is known by the server
>   but is not supported by the target resource.

Comment: This should not be the case because I have written python code that retrieves the html, edits it, and PUTS it back via the API and it works without any issues. So the API supports editing but somehow, I'm running into issues when transferring my code to nodejs.